# how to reset program to main string args?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I am writing a program and if it catches an Exception I want to reset the whole program is there anyway please tell me I really need to finish it tonight ?

```
public static void readinfile(ArrayList<ArrayList> table,
            int numberOfColumns,ArrayList<String> header, 
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> original,
            ArrayList<String> sntypes, ArrayList<Integer> displaySize, 
            ArrayList<String> writeOut, Scanner inputStream) {
        //System.out.print("enter data file: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter data file: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        try {
            System.out.println("try " + fileName);
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            System.out.println(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException E) {
            System.out.println("Error in opening file ");
            //readinfile(table, numberOfColumns, header,
            //original, sntypes,displaySize, writeOut, inputStream );
        }
        // file is now open and input scanner attached
        if (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String Line = inputStream.nextLine();
            Scanner lineparse = new Scanner(Line);
            lineparse.useDelimiter(",");
            ArrayList<String> rowOne = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (lineparse.hasNext()) {
                String temp = lineparse.next();
                String originaltemp = temp;
                writeOut.add(temp);
                temp = temp + "(" + (++numberOfColumns) + ")";
                displaySize.add(temp.length());
                // row.add(lineparse.next());
                if (temp.trim().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("S ")
                        || temp.trim().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("N ")) {
                    rowOne.add(originaltemp);
                    header.add(temp.substring(2));
                    sntypes.add(temp.toUpperCase().substring(0, 2).trim());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid file please enter a new file: ");
//readinfile(table, numberOfColumns, header, original, sntypes,displaySize,writeOut,Name);                  
                    readinfile(table, numberOfColumns, header,
                            original, sntypes, displaySize, writeOut, inputStream);
                }
            }
            // add table here it gives problem later on...
            original.add(rowOne);
        }

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String Line = inputStream.nextLine();
            Scanner lineparse = new Scanner(Line);
            lineparse.useDelimiter(",");
            ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
            int j = 0;
            while (lineparse.hasNextLine()) {
                String temp = lineparse.next().trim();
                int sizeOfrow = temp.trim().length();
                if (sizeOfrow > displaySize.get(j)) {
                    displaySize.set(j, sizeOfrow);
                }
                if (j < numberOfColumns && sntypes.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    try {
                        if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            row.add(new Double(0.0));
                        } else {
                            row.add(new Double(temp.trim()));
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException E) {
                        System.out.println("Opps there is a mistake "
                                + "I was expecting a number and I found: " + temp);
                        System.out.println("This row will be ignored");
//                      break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        row.add((" "));
                    } else {
                        row.add(temp);
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
            if (row.size() == numberOfColumns) {
                table.add(row);
            }
        }// close for while
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? What kind of program? GUI? Command line?

Answer (score 2):

homework?

Here's a clue on how to think about it:

```
  main:
    start loop
      start
        do stuff
        set ok to end
      catch exception
        set not ok to end
    loop if not ok to end
```

Comment: I already have the code the problem is the code keeps reseting which another method and I thought why the heck not just reset the whole program.

Comment: @chuck if you already have the code then why don't you post it so we can tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: Why don't you for gods sake tell us what you mean with "reset"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you meant this, but the following code will run again and again until it succeeds (as in: doesn't throw an exception):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    while(true){
        try{
            // execute your code
            break; // if successful, exit loop
        }catch(SomeException e){
            // handle exception
        }catch(SomeOtherException e){
            // handle exception
        }finally{
            // clean up, if necessary
        }
    }

}
```

Note: `while(true)` is an awful construct that I'm sure your teachers won't like. Perhaps you'll find a better way to rephrase that.

Comment: Also note that if this really "resets" the program depends on what kind of side-effects `doSomeStuff` has. It might very well be in a rather inconsistent state after the exception. And if you just run it again, it may just keep throwing the same exception. You should probably think about what kind of Exception you want to result in a retry.

Comment: @Thilo, true, added some more specific details

Comment: *while(true) is an awful construct*, indeed `for(;;)` for the win :)

Comment: @bestsss that's only slightly less awful :-)

Comment: @Sean, I disagree!! I often use the construct, it's very, very useful in lock-free when you need to CAS (compare and set). Like `if (object.cas(state, newState)) break;` That's how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but you could try calling the main method again, passing the arguments. As long as you didn't modify the string array of arguments, just call `main(args);` from a try/catch block in the main routine. Of course, if the exception keeps happening you'll loop infinitely and blow the stack:P